# How to escape bind variable (from Markdown) in Query?

Tags: sql, mongodb, slamdata

I created a markdown that will render a dropdown with values like these:

```
\server01\mis-home$\chq-blah\Scripts\Foo B Files.abc
\server02\mis-home$\chq-blah\Scripts\Bar G Files.abc
C:\Workspace\My_App\Resources\Export_Process.abc
```

When one of these values selected, subsequent query fails.

**Markdown**

```
Script = {!`MY AWESOME SELECT STATEMENT`}
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM myDB
WHERE scriptName =: Script
```

I suspect that's because of illegal characters such as space, backslash or underscore or dot.   How do I tell Slamdata to escape those?

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference a variable in SQL<sup>2</sup>, you must use the syntax `:var_name`, with no space between `:` and `var_name`.

If you change your query to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE scriptName = :Script
```

Then it should function correctly.

SQL<sup>2</sup> is more thoroughly documented on the [Quasar Analytics](http://quasar-analytics.org) website.

Comment: Thanks John.  That was it!